# how to Find a patricular table Table on a SQL Server across all Databases?

Tags: sql-server

I want to find a table in SQL Server, let's say "XYZ".  i don't know in which DB it is located. The server has many DBs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM sys.Tables
WHERE
name LIKE '%XYZ%'
```

You can make use of SP `sp_Msforeachdb` - this will be executed on every single database you have in the server.

```
EXEC sp_Msforeachdb "USE [?]; SELECT '[?]' dbname, * 
FROM sys.tables
WHERE name like '%XYA%'"
```

Comment: will it scan all the databases ?

Comment: Edited my answer, please check

Comment: do i need to select a Db as default ? for eg : i have selected a db -"abc" and table is present in db "123" so will the query fetch the table from 123 db ?

Comment: That's why `WHERE name like '%XYA%'` is used

Comment: No problem, glad it did :)

Answer (score 0):

This query will return a listing of all tables in all databases on a SQL instance:

```
DECLARE @command varchar(1000) 
SELECT @command = 'USE ? SELECT name FROM sysobjects WHERE xtype = ''U'' AND Name LIKE ''%A'' ORDER BY name' 
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @command
```